# Can gcc produce binary for Arm without cross compilation

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, gnu-toolchain, linux-toolchain

Can we configure gcc running on intel x64 architecture to produce binary for ARM chip by just passing some flags to gcc and not using a cross compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short: Nope

**Compiler:**
gcc is not a native crosscompiler, the target architecture has to be specified at the time you compile gcc. (Some exceptions apply, as for example x86 and x86_64 can be supported at the same time)

clang would be a native crosscompiler, and you can generate code for arm by passing -target=arm-linux-gnu, but you still cant produce binaries, as you need a linker and a C-library too. Means you can run `clang -target=arm-linux-gnu -c <your file>` and compile C/C++ Code (will likely need to point it to your C/C++ include paths) - but you cant build binaries.

**Rest of the toolchain:**
You need a fitting linker and toolchain too, both are specific to the architecture **and OS** you want to run at.

**Possible solutions:**
Get a fitting toolchain, or compile your own. For arm linux you have for ex. [CrossToolchains](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains) if you are on debian, for barebones you can get a crosscompiler from codesourcery.

Since you were very vague, its not possible to give you a clearer answer